# Recurrence Relation without using Master Theorem

Tags: series, recurrence

I can easily solve some recurrence relations using the master theorem but I want to understand how to solve them w/o using the theorem

EX:

```
T(n) = 5T(n/2) + O(n)  T(1) =1
```

Answer: `O(n^{log_2(5)}`

Expanding,

```
T(n) = 5T(n/2) + cn = 5(5T(n/4) + c(n/2)) + cn =



..... = 5^i * T(n/(2^i)) + cn*(1 + (5/2) + (5/2)^2 +......+ (5/2)^i)

Now let i= log_2(n)
```

then

```
5^(log_2(n)) * T(1) + cn*(1 + (5/2) + (5/2)^2 +......+ (5/2)^(log_2(n)))
```

After this I am lost . How do I get something similar to `n^{log_2(5)`?

Update:
Using the formula for the sum of geometric series (Sum = a*  (1-r^n)/(1-r))

I get `Sum = 1*(1-(5/2)^{log_2(n)})/(-3/2) = 2/3*c*(5^{log_2(n)} - n`

How are `5^{log_2(n)}` and `n^{log_2(5)}` related?
Thanks :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not check the rest of your calculation, but note that

```
a^b = exp(b * ln(a))
```

and

```
log_b(a) = ln(a) / ln(b)
```

And thus

```
5^{log_2(n)} = exp(log_2(n) * ln(5)) = exp(ln(n) / ln(2) * ln(5))
```

and also

```
n^{log_2(5)} = exp(ln(5) / ln(2) * ln(n))
```

Comment: Thanks do much ! :D This problem was bothering me